# Supervisord and ruby 1.9.2 - sleep cause SIGTERM

Tags: ruby, process, supervisord

I'm using supervisord on a mac (10.7.2) to manage background ruby processes.

When I launch a ruby script via supervisor, if the script contains a `sleep()`, in order to lower cpu usage, it receives a `SIGTERM` and stop execution, even if for the supervisor the process is still running.